# My UpdateView does show errors on fly orm

Tags: python, django

I have an update view which displays a form (based on some criteria).  I can update my model successfully, but if I enter bad data (like a bad time field), I do not get any errors back, I simply get a refresh of the update form.
My view looks like this:

```
class Cd_MixedView(UpdateView):
  model = Track
  template_name = 'cd_mixed_view.html'
  form_class = TrackForm
  context_object_name = 'cd_edit'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Cd_MixedView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    cur_track = Track.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    context['form'] = TrackForm(instance=cur_track)
    context['cd_info'] = Cd.objects.get(id=cur_track.cd_id.pk)
    return context

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form = self.get_form()

    if form.is_valid():
      return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
      return self.form_invalid(form)

  def form_valid(self,form):
    form.save()
    return super(Cd_MixedView, self).form_valid(form)

  def form_invalid(self,form):
      print("Form Invalid")
      return super(Cd_MixedView,self).form_invalid(form)
```

My template is the following:

```
<!-- templates/cd_mixed_view.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} CD Details{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<h1>CD Update Track </h1>
{% if cd_info %}
  <p>Artist Name:&nbsp;{{ cd_info.artist_name}}
  <p>Cd Title:&nbsp;{{ cd_info.cd_title }}
  <p>Cd Total Time:&nbsp;{{ cd_info.cd_total_time|time:"H:i:s" }}
  <p>Cd Run Time:&nbsp;{{ cd_info.cd_run_time|time:"H:i:s" }}
  <p>Cd Remaining Time:&nbsp;
  {% if cd_info.cd_run_time_delta > cd_info.cd_total_time_delta %}
    (-{{ cd_info.cd_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }})
  {% else %}
    {{ cd_info.cd_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }}
  {% endif %}
  <TABLE BORDER="0" TABLE_LAYOUT="fixed" WIDTH="100%">
    <TR BGCOLOR="#B0B0FF">
      <TD ALIGN="Center">&nbsp;Track #</TD>
      <TD ALIGN="Center"> Cut Title</TD>
      <TD ALIGN="Center">Track Length</TD>
      <TD ALIGN="Center" BGCOLOR="#CC99CC">Run Time</TD>
      <TD ALIGN="Center" BGCOLOR="#CC99CC">Time Remaining</TD>
    </TR>
    {% for tracks in cd_info.cd_tracks.all %}
      {% if tracks.id != cd_edit.pk %}
        <TR>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top" WIDTH="10">&nbsp;{{ tracks.track_number }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">&nbsp;{{ tracks.track_title }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ tracks.trk_length_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="Left" VALIGN="Top">{{ tracks.trk_run_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
          {% if tracks.trk_run_time_delta > cd_info.cd_total_time_delta %}
            <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;(-{{ tracks.trk_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }})</TD>
          {% else %}
            <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Left">&nbsp;{{ tracks.trk_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
          {% endif %}
        </TR>
      {% else %}
        <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form }}
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Update Track Values"></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
        {% if form.errors %}
          <p>There were some errors in the information you entered. Please correct the following:</p>
            <ul>
              {% for field in form %}
                {% if field.errors %}
                  <li>{{ field.label }}:
                  {{ field.errors|striptags }}</li>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </TABLE>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

The form itself is the following:

```
class TrackForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Track
      exclude = ('trk_length_time_delta',
        'trk_run_time',
        'trk_run_time_delta'   ,
        'trk_remaining_time',
        'trk_remaining_time_delta',
      )
      widgets = {
          'cd_id': forms.HiddenInput()
      }
```

I even put a print in the invalid_form function - so it seems to know the form is invalid,
but it just redisplays my form with the previous data.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `UpdateView` **yet** for some reason you go and redefine most of it's useful methods while not even making any useful or new changes. The main problem is that you override `get_context_data` and overwrite the form while manually defining it even though the super method has already added the form properly to the context.

Let `UpdateView` do it's job most of the code you write is not needed as `UpdateView` already does that:

```py
class Cd_MixedView(UpdateView):
    model = Track
    template_name = 'cd_mixed_view.html'
    form_class = TrackForm
    context_object_name = 'cd_edit'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Cd_MixedView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        cur_track = self.object # no need to get the object again it is already present in `self.object`
        # form is already added to context by super method
        context['cd_info'] = Cd.objects.get(id=cur_track.cd_id.pk)
        return context
    # `post`, `form_valid` and `form_invalid` methods were same as super so no need to write yourself
```